# Media queries not working on Iphone but fine on browser resize

Tags: css, wordpress, media-queries

Hi Im currently using a Boilerplate theme called Bones on a WordPress but Im having problems making the responsive menu work on my Iphone. When I manually resize the menu seems to work

the media query im using is

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {

the site im trying to get to work is here:[link](http://www.optimise-website-marketing.com)

Any help would be much appreciated as I have gone to the theme writer and he hasn't responded in days

Comment: Did you include the media="screen" in the head of the html ? (in <script>)

Answer (score 16):

have you used the meta viewport object? Put this in the head of your document

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, This now works on the IPhone but has the IPhone and small device menu on the larger Desktop site when on IE8!! I’ll look into this now, but any ideas how to fix? maybe a stylesheet just for this browser.

Comment: No problem, this because ie does not support media queries and so all styles after your first @media will be ignored, the best fix I have seen to get media queries working in ie is a bit of javascript http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/ I hope this helps

Comment: THanks KZA absolute ledgend!! I seem to have a Margin on my Iphone that I cant get rid of now. I would like my content to go 100% width but after margin:0px everything I still have a margin border>? andy advice?

Comment: Heres a screen shot
http://optimise-website-marketing.com/wp-content/themes/bones/images/photo.PNG

Comment: there is a tool for iphone to resize browser and change user-agent that may be useful in testing this: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/browser-resizer/id648937670?mt=8

Comment: Hi, it is a good practice not to use maximum-scale=1 as it unables users from zooming.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to mention Media like this  for iphone and smartphones

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: You don't **need** to use min and max values for media queries. It can help avoid certain conflicts, but so can stacking them in an intelligent way.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across an issue where, when I loaded my stylesheet with this:

```
<link src="mobile.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 400px)" />
```

and then within `mobile.css`, I had a couple of styles like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}

h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

and several devices (iPhone, iPad - with a different breakpoint of course, and Galaxy Nexus) did not see the `background:red;` rule ("nested" media query), only those that were *outside* of the "inline" media query (`h1`).  Chrome and other browsers were fine with it, however.

Comment: To that point, he's got print styles in a stylesheet that's set for `media="screen"`, so they won't work.

Comment: I tested this again recently and did not have this trouble, in iPhone6/iOS8/Chrome, iPhone6/iOS8/Safari, Samsung S5/4.4.2/Chrome, Samsung S5/4.4.2/Stock, Samsung S5/4.4.2/Firefox, iPad1/iOS5/Safari, Nexus7/4.4.4/Chrome, HTC One/4.4.2/Chrome, S2 Tablet/4.0/Chrome,S2 Tablet/4.0/Stock, S2 Tablet/4.0/Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This jumped out at me as weird:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    ... 
}
```

I believe that should be

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), 
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    ... 
}
```

or...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (max-device-width: 480px) { 
    ... 
}
```

You might also want to consider moving from XHTML to HTML5 for your doctype.