# Media query is not working in my Iphone but is working in browser when i resize my browser

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have also use this meta tage but still not picked my Iphone how can i fixed ?? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: It should work, the problem has to be elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media queries not working on Iphone but fine on browser resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241617/media-queries-not-working-on-iphone-but-fine-on-browser-resize)

Comment: Please post your code. Use jsfiddle.net if required but also post your code here for legacy issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try making it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

if you absolutely MUST disable zooming.

Comment: Yes i already used this but thay still not working :( <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">

Comment: make it initial-scale=1

Comment: but we need initial scale = 0 because we don't want to zoom the page

Comment: add maximum-scale=1 to disable zooming

Comment: Disabling zoom is pretty user-hostile anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
```